# Why does substr(clob,1) make query way faster in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, clob

```
create table messages {
    id number(38,0) generated by default as identity not null,
    create_timestamp timestamp(6) default current_timestamp,
    message clob
}
```

This table has about 5 million rows. There are no indexes except for the primary key which is auto generated.

The 2 following queries return the same data:

```
select m.id,
       m.create_timestamp,
       m.message
from message m;
```

```
select m.id,
       m.create_timestamp,
       substr(m.message,1)
from message m;
```

Fetching 1000 rows gives these results:

Query 1: Execution: 2503 ms, Fetch: 37988 ms

Query 2: Execution: 255 ms, Fetch: 7 ms

How could there be such a huge discrepancy in performance if the same data is returned? Also I would expect the 2nd query to actually be a bit slower because of the extra logic.

Comment: Just run the same query twice, you will see that the second run will take less exec time. This is because the first run will perform the disk reads and will leave most of the data in ram (cached), allowing the second query to find them there, thus saving the disk reads .

Comment: No, the 2nd query runs way faster even if I ran it first.

Comment: LOBs have a number of optimizations.  In particular, when SUBSTR() is called on a LOB, temporary lobs are created that can impact performance.  See https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adlob/performance-guidelines.html#GUID-0EA0E7B7-96E6-4393-B2DA-1F2CA72A72B7 for details.

Comment: What version of Oracle database are you using, and what client are you using to test? Are you executing this once from a client program on your local device or in a loop within PL/SQL ? If a client program, check to see if you have any options set for handling LOBs. It sounds to me like the behavior you'd get if you wrapped that SUBSTR in a CAST and your data just happened to be < 4000 bytes. For example, CAST(SUBSTR(message,1,4000) AS varchar2(4000)) will give you a varchar2 which will fetch orders of magnitude faster than a CLOB of equivalent length. But a SUBSTR by itself should return LOB.

Comment: @PaulW Db is 19c. I have tested running the queries in both DBeaver and Oracle SQL developer. I have tried many combinations, running them multiple times, different order, etc. About 60% of the clobs are ABOVE 4000 bytes.

Comment: When you see the 1000 rows your test fetched, do you see the full CLOB values, including those in excess of 4KB ?

One of the difficulties here is how different client programs handle LOB data. Oracle returns a pointer ("LOB locator") and the client is then responsible for making additional calls to the database to open the LOB, read from the LOB repeatedly until reaching the end, then close the LOB. But a client could do something differently to make things more performant, like automatically casting to varchar2 or postponing the LOB read. Look through your client's options/preferences.